# jQuery get request with json body to a REST api

Tags: jquery, json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm building a website with django and django_rest_framework.
I tested the rest api with httpie.

But when I try to do the same call with jQuery I get an error.

```
jquery.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:8000/api/recentposts/?{%22last_id%22:1650} 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

The call with httpie is the following

```
http get localhost:8000/api/recentposts/ last_id=1650
```

or

```
http get localhost:8000/api/recentposts/ < recent.json
----------------------------
content of recent.json 
{
    "last_id": 1650
}
```

and I get the right results.

while with jquery I tried

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/recentposts/',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    data: JSON.stringify({ last_id : 1650 }),
    success: function(resp){
        console.log(resp);
    }
});
```

Is there something wrong with the call?
I've tried with .get instead of .ajax, and a lot of different ways to pass the json but I haven't solved anything yet.

by the way this is the view that is called

```
class RecentPostViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    '''
    ViewSet that displays recent posts after it post id

    It needs a JSON file like the following
    {
        "last_id" : int
    }
    '''
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        recent_feed = Post.objects.filter(hidden=False).order_by('-pub_date').filter(pk__gt=request.data['last_id'])

        log.warning("incoming request")
        log.warning(dir(request))
        log.warning(request.data)
        log.warning(request.query_params)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(recent_feed, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Is this beacause jQuery get call is not capable to do a get request with a json body? Or I'm getting something wrong?
By the way I'm using jQuery 3.1.1

Comment: What happens if you remove the `contentType` and `processData` options, and just do `data: { last_id : 1650 },`

Comment: A GET has no body...it only uses the url. Therefore there is no `contentType` either

Comment: There's still the same result.

Comment: Is there any kind of javascript library to make rest requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `$.param` function when you build a GET request (and not the `JSON.Stringify` function).

```
 data: $.param({'last_id' : 1650 }),
```

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/',
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    data: $.param({'last_id' : 1650 }),
    success: function(resp){
        console.log(resp);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you remove `processData: false` the data will be processed by `$.param()` internally by default

Comment: Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Also there is no `contentType` for a GET